# How to set the future permissions of content in folder

Tags: permissions, samba, chmod, chown

Let's say I am the user Alice and I have a publicly accessible folder `/samba/public`

The permissions of the public Samba folder (`/samba/public/`) are nobody:nogroup and 0777.

When Alice tries to copy over something from her home folder to the shared public drive

(e.g `cp ~/Downloads/* /samba/public`),

Alice wants the newly copied files to be editable/deletable by all guests who have access to the public Samba share.

I want the copied files to be owned by nobody:nogroup and set to 0777.

Instead, what happens is that the newly copied files are owned by alice:alice and guest users on the public drive can't edit or delete the files.

How can I ensure that future copy/move operations of content from Alice's home folder to the shared/public Samba folder will be owned by nobody:nogroup so that guest users aren't then prevented from deleting/editing the files themselves?

Comment: @sourcejedi One idea that I've thought of so far is to run a cron job every 5 minutes that "resets" permissions recursively on the contents of the public directory so that any newly pasted Alice-owned files become nobody-owned files. However, this feels like  a very inelegant way of addressing an underlying problem.

Comment: I have the same frustration - the question I linked is my own :). Some day I might write a script which uses `inotify` to detect newly created files, and changes the permissions immediately, I think it would work quite nicely for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to U&L! You probably don't need files to become nobody:nogroup 0777. I am very sorry but the pattern you would want was broken by Gnome/systemd (and udisks). At least, if Alice uses these *on the same computer that runs the Samba server*.

This is discussed (not very clearly) in the questions [Shared, read-write, photo directory tree, for normal users](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278396/shared-read-write-photo-directory-tree-for-normal-users) and [Share folder/files between multiple users on ext4 disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450286/share-folder-files-between-multiple-users-on-ext4-disk)

If Alice *isn't* using Gnome (including the Gnome file manager), nor udisks  (to allow users to mount removable filesystems ) on the same computer that runs the Samba server, then you might actually be able to use the original [User Private Groups](https://security.ias.edu/how-and-why-user-private-groups-unix) pattern.

IIRC, Redhat systems already set the correct umask for UPG.  For Debian-based systems, you might need to enable and configure pam_umask.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask

EDIT: if you have to change the `umask`, you will also have to change the access mode of any *existing* files, that you might want to share in future.  E.g. `chmod -R g+w $HOME/*` or `chmod -R g+w /home/*/*`.  Do *not* use `chmod -R g+w $HOME`.  It will change the mode of `$HOME/.ssh`, and likely stop you logging in using `ssh`.

---

Otherwise, maybe someone can suggest a workaround based on this information.

I can suggest one alternative, based on the thread [Setting up permissions for common folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176952/setting-up-permissions-for-common-folder?rq=1)

It sounds like you want the guest users to be able to delete and edit these files... this suggests they might not be very big files.

From the information you give, it seems Alice could act as a guest herself, using the Samba share to upload the files.  ...you just have to avoid telling Alice where the Samba directory is on the server.  And if she's smart enough to find it, she's smart enough to be told that computers were a mistake and her perfectly logical idea will not work because Reasons.

(If you absolutely needed to, you could "hide" the Samba server by running it inside a container such as LXC.)

In case Alice has an account on the Samba server which is not a guest, it might also be necessary to use `chmod g+s` on the directory, and in `smb.conf` set

```
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt the "setting up perms for common folder" workaround and I'll report back! In my case, this is a Ubuntu Sever OS installed on a NUC and "Alice" is an SSH user so Gnome doesn't apply here.

Comment: @chivano if Alice connects via SSH the `create mask` and `directory mask` won't do anything if she logs in and creates a file/directory - they only affect things done via Samba.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck with the "Setting up permissions for common folder" solution. Even though "Alice" and nobody both belong to the newly created group and even though the group owns the public folder, when Alice copies something over, nobody is still unable to edit/delete.

Comment: @sourcejedi I'm reading through the UPG blog post but I'm not sure I get it...is it as simple as performing `chmod g+s`? Alice (the user) already belongs to a group called Alice but nobody only belongs to a group called nogroup (and a group called samba_public_access which I created for test purposes). Is there anything preventing me from assigning nobody to a group called nobody when they already exist in a group called nogroup?

Comment: Maybe I should add that when Alice transfers files over to the public folder, this is happening via SSH and NOT via Samba. Meanwhile, the guest who's trying to delete a file/folder that Alice pasted into the public folder is attempting to do so via Windows Explorer. I could be wrong but I suppose this means we can rule out an incorrect smb.conf config because Alice isn't copying files via Samba. She's literally just copying a file from one location to another on the same drive.

Comment: @chivano As you say, the "user private group" (group Alice for user Alice) part is already set up by default on any distribution. You need 1) chmod g+s /shared-directory 2) ensure Alice runs with a umask of 002, not 022. 3) make sure the other user (e.g. nobody) is a member of the group which owns /shared-directory... I think that's all you need to use UPG as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79821/discussion-between-chivano-and-sourcejedi).

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have got this fixed now (touch wood).

I've tried various different fixes so it's hard to identify what precisely made everything work but these are the steps which I think helped:

---

1. I have a [Docker application](https://hub.docker.com/r/jlesage/jdownloader-2/) running which downloads content to my home directory (this seemed irrelevant at the time).

---

2. After following the advice of @sourcejedi, my `umask` was changed to `0002`.
3. Following the advice given by @Isaac, I was able to create/copy/move files as well as directories from my home directory to `/samba/public/` and Samba guest users were able to rename/edit/delete freely.

---

4. However, when I tried to copy/move anything in my home dir that was downloaded using this Docker application, Samba guest users were not able to rename/edit/delete freely (because the Docker app was creating directories with a chmod val of 755).
5. I then changed the `umask` of the Docker application to 0002. Subsequent downloads and directories generated by the Docker app were of chmod val 775. When these directories are copied over to `/samba/public/`, Samba guest users can now rename/edit/delete.

---

Footnotes:

- Changing umask to a value of your choice is as simple as performing `umask XXXX` where XXXX is the value you want. You can check your umask value by simply typing `umask` into the terminal.
- Changing the umask of the Docker application that I was using was done by adding a new ENV parameter called `umask` and setting that to `0002`. When starting a Docker container, you can pass in this parameter via CLI or if you use Portianer to manage your running containers, you can pass in this ENV parameter with the web-UI.
- **Major caveat:** As part of getting this working, I first tried following the advice given in the [Setting up permissions for common folder thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176952/setting-up-permissions-for-common-folder?rq=1) as well trying to use a User Private Groups (UPG) pattern that @sourcejedi recommended before following @Isaac's advice.

  If anyone in the future encounters similar issues, this might be relevant?

Comment: I would try to make clear that `umask XXXX` is temporary. I.e. if you need to run it, you need to run it each time you log in. E.g. the manual for the old RHEL 5 (redhat) says they already set the default umask by including `umask 002` in `/etc/bashrc`, which will be run when you ssh in, assuming you don't change the users shell to something different from `bash`.